# This interaction failed error on successful interaction [discord.py, discord.ui]

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have an embed help menu with pagination, when I switch pages, they switch successfully, though the under the embed, the error: This interaction failed. appears.

```
class HelpMenu(View):
    try:

        def __init__(self, ctx, data):
            super().__init__()

            self.ctx: commands.Context = ctx
            self.data = data
            self.current_page = 0
            self.per_page = 5
            self.timeout = None
            self.message = None

        async def show_page(self):
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title="Help",
                description="List of available commands",
                color=discord.Color.blurple(),
            )
            embed.set_footer(
                text=f"Page {self.current_page + 1}/{self.get_max_pages()}"
            )

            start_index = self.current_page * self.per_page
            end_index = start_index + self.per_page
            for name, value in self.data[start_index:end_index]:
                embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=False)

            if self.message is None:
                self.message = await self.ctx.send(embed=embed, view=self)
            else:
                await self.message.edit(embed=embed)

        def get_max_pages(self):
            return (len(self.data) + self.per_page - 1) // self.per_page

        @discord.ui.button(label="↩", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
        async def previous_page(
            self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction
        ):
            if self.current_page > 0:
                self.current_page -= 1
                await self.show_page()
            await self.ctx.defer()
            await interaction.response.defer()

        @discord.ui.button(label="↪", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
        async def next_page(
            self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction
        ):
            if self.current_page < self.get_max_pages() - 1:
                self.current_page += 1
                await self.show_page()
            await self.ctx.defer()
            await interaction.response.defer()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

@client.command(description="Shows this embed.")
async def help(ctx):
    try:
        commands_list = client.commands
        data = [(command.name, command.description) for command in commands_list]
        menu = HelpMenu(ctx, data)
        await menu.show_page()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I've tried deferring the interaction using interaction.reponse.defer() and ctx.defer(), though this didn't work.
There are no further errors in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it threw the console error that 'Button Object has no attribute "response"'.
I can't tell you exactly why it is but I think if you introduce a button in a class you have to do it like:

```
async def next_page(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
```

Meaning instead of introducing it like **"self-button-interaction"** you have to do it like **"self-interaction-button"**. After I did this to your page buttons in worked for me.